# CollectionViewをスクロールすると表示が崩れる

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

現在`CollectionView`に0〜299までの数字を持ったセルがあり、1という数字が表示されているセルの横にラインを引いたのですが、
下にスクロールしていくと関係のない107や222といった数字のセルにラインが引かれて表示されてしまいます。何度も何度もスクロールをしていくとどんどんラインが増殖していきます。`cellForItemAtIndexPath`におけるセルの再利用方法に問題があるのでしょうか？
また、`cellForItemAtIndexPath`内で毎回`BoundaryLineSide`のインスタンスを生成していることが原因かと思い`ViewDidLoad`で一回だけ生成してラインを描画させるようにしたのですが、これでも1とは関係のない数字のセルにラインが引かれました。
下記のコードのどこに問題があるのでしょうか？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
     numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 300;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NumberCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"
                                                                                forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.number.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row];

    if ([cell.number.text isEqual: @"1"]) {
        BoundaryLineSide *boundarySide = [[BoundaryLineSide alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
        [cell addSubview:boundarySide];
    }

    return cell;
}



@implementation BoundaryLineSide

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGRect bounds_ = rect;
    CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
    border.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0.0f, 2.0f, bounds_.size.height);
    border.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    [self.layer addSublayer:border];
}
```

Comment: 前に使った時に引いたライン残っているのだと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。試しに if (indexPath.row >= 111) { [boundarySide removeFromSuperview];  } とすると1のセルのみにラインを引くことができました。誠にありがとうございます。やはりあまりセルの再利用の理解が進んでないと思うのですが、カスタムセルのnumberプロパティにはそれぞれ0〜299の個別の値が設定されていてセルにも表示されるにもかかわらず、なぜ描画したラインは1のセルのみに適用されず他のセルにも適用されるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NumberCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"
                                                                      forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.number.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row];

    if ([cell.number.text isEqual: @"1"]) {
        BoundaryLineSide *boundarySide = [[BoundaryLineSide alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
        [cell addSubview:boundarySide];
```

いちど`addSubview:`したら、そのセルが再利用されたときにも、`boundarySide`は、セルに貼り付けられたままです。セルのテキストが`"1"`ではなく、かつセルの`subviews`に`boundarySide`が含まれているとしたら、`boundarySide`を`removeFromSuperview`しなければいけません。
（私なら、`addSubview:`と`removeFromSuperview`をくり返すのは、ハードウェアにとってもめんどくさいことなので、セルには固定でラインを貼り付けたままにしておいて、ラインの`hidden`属性をコントロールすることを考えます。）

```
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。比較を行うにはそれに適したメソッドを使わないと動作がおかしくなるのですね。修正します。addSubviewをすれば再利用された時もセルにオブジェクトは張り付いたままなのですね。一度removeFromSuperviewで実行するとセルのラインを消すことができたのですが、ご提示のようにhidden属性をNOにしたいと思います。詳細な解説で理解できました。誠にありがとうございました。

Comment: `isEqual:`メソッドはそれぞれのクラスごとに適切にオーバーライドされていることを期待しているので、NSStringにおいて同じ文字列かどうか、を比較するのに用いるのは間違いではありません。
同じアドレスかどうか、で比較するのであれば単に`==`演算子を使います。
ポインタの指すアドレスが異なっていても同じ文字列なら`isEqual:`メソッドで`true`が返ることは、次のようなコードで確認できます。
NSString *s1 = @"string";
NSString *s2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"string"];
NSLog(@"%d", s1 == s2); // false
NSLog(@"%d", [s1 isEqual:s2]); // true
NSLog(@"%d", [s1 isEqualToString:s2]); // true

NSStringのドキュメントにも書いてあるとおり、比較対象のオブジェクトの型がNSStringだとわかっている場合は、`isEqualToString:`の方が速い、というものになります。

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi さん、isEqualメソッドの詳しい解説ありがとうございます。